# Condense a python expression of multiplication of list of tuples with float

Tags: python, list

Given weights, and bias, I wanted to multiply the weights with float and add a bias term. However, it is not possible to multiply a sequence with a float, but I want to condense this form, what is a convenient way to condense the expressions?

```
weights=[(2,6),(3,5),(5,4)]
bias=[2,-2.2,-3]
score1 = weights[0][0] * 0.4 + weights[0][1] * 0.6 + bias[0]
score2 = weights[1][0] * 0.4 + weights[1][1] * 0.6 + bias[1]
score3 = weights[2][0] * 0.4 + weights[2][1] * 0.6 + bias[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
[w1*0.4 + w2*0.6 +b for (w1, w2), b in zip(weights, bias)]
# [6.3999999999999995, 2.0, 1.4000000000000004]
```

---

If you want to store them as separate variables:

```
score1, score2, score3 = (w1*0.4 + w2*0.6 +b for (w1, w2), b in zip(weights, bias))
```